# Sync files between 2 macs

Tags: data-synchronization

I want to synchronise files normally stored on a desktop Mac - which is in use by my customer's partner under his AppleID, while using my laptop, logged under my customer's AppleID, while away from home.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Did you take a look at one of the various file storage and sync service such as Dropbox, Google Drive and Box? They provide the facility to have shared folders which can be used across different account while sharing some files/folders.

Comment: Thanks for this.

I started out thinking that iCloud would do this effortlessly; however, what I've found so far is that neither iCloud - owing to the ID conflict - nor Gdrive, nor OneDrive make this easy. So the Dropbox option is beginning to look like my fallback solution, despite the 2GB free storage limit.

Comment: You can start by sending invite from one of your existing Dropbox accounts for a new account to be created for this purpose. That way you'll get an additional 512 MB of bonus storage space.

Comment: Would "Back to my Mac" be useful?  It allows access to shared drives and the remote desktop?

Comment: "Back to my Mac" is no longer available in macOS Mojave.  That's a pretty good indication that its days are numbered.  So I would not recommend even considering that route.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a 3rd party online storage and synchronization solution such as [Dropbox](http://dropbox.com).

Dropbox also offers support for shared folders, so you can have two separate Dropbox accounts one for your customers partner and one yourself, while having folder(s) shared among the two accounts.

Dropbox has native macOS, Windows and Linux clients available along with mobile apps for iOS and Android.

If you plan on creating new Dropbox accounts, consider leveraging [Dropbox referral benefit](https://www.dropbox.com/help/space/earn-space-referring-friends) which will offer additional bonus to both referrer and referee.

Answer (score 2):

You could use something like [ChronoSync](https://www.econtechnologies.com/chronosync/overview.html) in concert with [ChronoAgent](https://www.econtechnologies.com/chronoagent/overview.html) and you would be able to sync files between the two Macs across the Internet.  ChronoSync is the actual syncing software, and ChronoAgent is a client that gives ChronoSync access to a remote system.